# How to add UIScroller in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with different cells and I need to add a scroller view with special UI in some cells:

[image: Desired look]

I need to develop the UI which you can see in *section 0.*
So my questions are:

1. How can I add a scroller view?
2. How can I load data only for those items which are shown right now?
3. How can I change the width of "Line" column after scrolling to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer as best I can with some starting pointers for you...

1. You need to subclass UITableViewCell and in your subclasses `drawRect` method you should add a `UIScrollView` to the `contentView`.
2. Not totally sure what you mean here, please expand.
3. In your new table cell, set it as the delegate of the scroll view you implemented, then you''ll get callbacks when the scrollview scroll with the `contentOffset` value, which you can use to calculate how much to grow or shrink the line items.

Comment: 2. I mean functionality has to load data only for items which are visible

Comment: In the tableview or the scrollview? The tableview does it for you. The scroll view you'd be able to use the same callback giving content offset to display or hide content based on scrolling position.

Comment: Why would you add the UIScrollView as a subview of the UITableViewCell subclass in drawRect:? awakeFromNib, initWithFrame:, or initWithCoder: would be better places.

Comment: Yup valid, it was late, I was tired :)